# how can i change the image size that loads in woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In my website i have a slider that loads the 620*620 size of the products picture. I want to load other size of this picture (the sizes that i want are created in wordpress gallery but i dont know how to load them).
the default picture size in "woocomerce_thumbnail" . 
what is the other size that i can use  ?

i found something here but how i can change this default size? (what is the other sizes that i can use ?)

```
if (!function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {

    /**
     * Get the product thumbnail, or the placeholder if not set.
     *
     * @param string $size (default: 'woocommerce_thumbnail').
     * @param int    $deprecated1 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0).
     * @param int    $deprecated2 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0).
     * @return string
     */
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail', $deprecated1 = 0, $deprecated2 = 0 ) {
        global $product;

        $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );

        return $product ? $product->get_image( $image_size ) : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-check your theme support `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`

**For only woocommerce you can try this**

```
if (!function_exists('firefog_woocommerce_image_dimensions')) {
    function firefog_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
        global $pagenow;

        if ( ! isset( $_GET['activated'] ) || $pagenow != 'themes.php' ) {
            return;
        }

        $catalog = array(
            'width'     => '300',   // px
            'height'    => '300',   // px
            'crop'      => 1        // true
        );

        $single = array(
            'width'     => '500',   // px
            'height'    => '500',   // px
            'crop'      => 1        // true
        );

        $thumbnail = array(
            'width'     => '100',   // px
            'height'    => '100',   // px
            'crop'      => 1        // true
        );

        // Image sizes
        update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
        update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', $single );         // Single product image
        update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', $thumbnail );   // Image gallery thumbs
    }
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'firefog_woocommerce_image_dimensions', 1 );
```

**For Default WordPress Thumbnail**

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

**If You need a specific resolutions**

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(500, 500) );  // 500x500 dimension
```

**Post Thumbnail Linking to Large Image Size** you can change the size by changing `large`

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
    if ( ! empty( $large_image_url[0] ) ) {
        printf( '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( $large_image_url[0] ),
            esc_attr( get_the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
            get_the_post_thumbnail()
        );
    }
}
```

**You can also create custom featured image sizes in your theme’s functions**

```
 add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 300, 300); //Simple widget size
 add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', 120, 120, true ); // Hard Crop Mode
 add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180 ); // Soft Crop Mode
 add_image_size( 'singlepost-thumb', 590, 9999 ); // Unlimited Height Mode
```

**Here is an example of how to create custom Featured Image sizes in your theme’s `functions.php` file.**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 300, 300); // 300 pixels wide 
 }
```

**Displaying additional image sizes in your WordPress theme**

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'your-specified-image-size' ); //Example singlepost-thumb
```

Answer (score 1):

> These sizes include:
>
> - `woocommerce_thumbnail` – used in the product ‘grids’ in places such as    the shop page.
> - `woocommerce_single` – used on single product pages.    woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail – used below the main image on the
>     single product page to switch the gallery.
> - `woocommerce_single` shows the full product image, as uploaded, so is    always uncropped by default. It defaults to 600px width.
>
> `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail` is always square cropped and defaults to
>   100×100 pixels. This is used for navigating images in the gallery.
>
> `woocommerce_thumbnail` defaults to 600px width, square cropped so the
>   product grids look neat. The aspect ratio for cropping can be
>   customized by the store owner.

You can find the above and information on defining custom sized [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/).